# Change margin of footnotes in beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, beamer-metropolis

I'd like for footnotes to be further down, to finish at the height where the numbering of pages does. This (hopefully, but not necessarily) without changing the area the text is written.

[image]

This is how I have it set up, couldn't find any information on how to do it online, please help. Thanks!

MWE (without aesthetics changes):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Trial Slide}
Text \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (for people who'd like to change the horizontal margin, that's shown at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700259/36296 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the space below the footnote is occupied by the footline, even if it is mostly empty. As a workaround you could remove the footline and use some other template to show the framenumber, e.g. the logo:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{logo}{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Trial Slide}
Text \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use the `moloch` theme, a more modern fork of the metropolis theme which has a much shorter footline by default:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Trial Slide}
Text \footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works very well but the number misaligned and now it's closer to the edge, is there a way to keep it in the same place?

Comment: I dont know if it's correct, but I was able to add vertical and horizontal spaces. My changes are `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace{6.7pt}}
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{%%
 \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
 \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
 \vspace{-7pt}
 \usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}\hspace{5pt}%
}`. Hope you will be able to correct if there was a better way.

Comment: @M.O. Moving the frame number by inserting spaces sounds just fine